# Nishikata hides 100% Unrequited Love from Takagi even though Takagi already knows

Tags: anime-production, manga-production, teasing-master-takagi-san

Maybe related: [How did Takagi know about 100% Unrequited Love in S01E04?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67623/how-did-takagi-know-about-100-unrequited-love-in-s01e04)

---

I watched Takagi-san out of order. In particular, I watched S01E07 before S01E05:

- In S01E05 "Bookstore" (Ch9), Takagi finds out Nishikata bought a
  volume of 100% Unrequited Love.
- In S01E07 "Shopping" (Ch37) Nishikata denies buying another volume
  and even makes an insane bet with Takagi.

So to me watching S01E05 after S01E07 I'm like...what was going on? Was it out of order production like in American animated series? I checked the manga chapters and apparently not.

I guess it's indeed no production order mistake but simply that Nishikata is just denying having bought a new volume even if Takagi **already knows** that Nishikata reads / watches 100% Unrequited Love...

**Question**: What is going on? Here's what I find weird.

1. i watched the powerpuff girls before, so i know the feeling. yes absolutely if it's just S01E07 without S01E05 it makes perfect sense. it's quite obvious why nishikata would want to hide if takagi doesn't ALREADY know. but given takagi already knows, i believe this additional embarrassment is only marginal. if you've spent 600 yen on a meal, then II don't think it's a big deal to spend an additional 20 yen for more ice or ketchup or whatever. I think there's a relevant English idiom / saying / aphorism here. There's 'In for a penny, in for a pound.' Here, you're already down a pound, I don't think it's a big deal to spend an additional penny.

The fact that takagi found out in S01E05 means nishikata is doomed to be teased by this anytime until death. hell i think even if nishikata stops watching 100% UL the fact that nishikata watched before is ammunition for teasing. I don't think it matters if takagi happens to see nishikata doing an action that takagi **already knows** nishikata does (assuming it's the kind of action that doesn't make a difference if someone is watching you do the action).

2. **The bet is insane.** There's no way takagi would get it wrong when takagi already knows. when i watched S01E07 i thought nishikata had maybe a 30-49% chance of bluffing takagi. I was so excited and thought 'Wow this is like that episode of Kaiji.' But when i watched S01E05, i think nishikata should have had at most a 5% chance of bluffing takagi and so I find the whole thing nonsensical.
3. Again, S01E07 makes perfect sense without S01E05. I think somehow Sōichirō Yagami - I-I-I mean - Yamamoto probably wrote those 2 chapters at the same time and forgot that they should be in opposite order or maybe only 1 of them should've been published as the origin story of when Takagi finds out about 100% UL. I don't think there's anything wrong with this kind of thinking. Let me know if you think there's something wrong with thinking this way eg S01E07 somehow depends on S01E05. Or maybe there's something like 1 is or is / was supposed to be a flashback or something.

Answer (score 1):

Going from inference...perhaps Nishikata was a bit shy about it?

The particular work appears to be something that would be atypical for a shonen such as himself to read or consume, and given that Takagi has teased him for a lot of *other* things, he probably wouldn't have wanted this to be used to tease him.

Comment: But Takagi already knows, so what's to hide? It makes sense if you just watch S01E07 without S01E05 of course.

Comment: Put yourself in the shoes of a prepubescent middle schooler who has a subtle crush on the girl that keeps teasing him.  Nishikata is already plenty clumsy and awkward around her, and his sentiment - even if she knows something - isn't to give her yet more ammo to be teased.  Teenagers in love very, *very* seldom think rationally, even less so when portrayed in anime.

Comment: 1 - i watched the powerpuff girls before, so i know the feeling. yes absolutely if it's just S01E07 without S01E05 it makes perfect sense. it's quite obvious why nishikata would want to hide if takagi doesn't ALREADY know.  but this embarrassment is only marginal. if you've spent 10,000 yen on something, then what's an additional 10 yen for some accessory? 2 - also what's up with the insane bet? there's no way takagi would get it wrong when takagi already knows. 3 - again, S01E07 makes perfect sense without S01E05. do you disagree? (I'll edit post.)