# How did Takagi know about 100% Unrequited Love in S01E04?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production, teasing-master-takagi-san

Maybe related: [Nishikata hides 100% Unrequited Love from Takagi even though Takagi already knows](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67597/nishikata-hides-100-unrequited-love-from-takagi-even-though-takagi-already-know)

---

I watched Takagi-san out of order. In particular I watched S01E07 before S01E04. (Maybe I also watched S01E05 before S01E04.)

- In S01E05 "Bookstore" (Ch9), Takagi finds out Nishikata bought a volume of 100% Unrequited Love.
- In S01E07 "Shopping" (Ch37) Nishikata denies buying another volume and even makes an insane bet with Takagi.

Question: In S01E04, how did takagi know that nishikata was up watching 100% Unrequited Love?

It makes sense if S01E04 takes place *after* S01E05 or S01E07 (maybe S01E05 or S01E07 is a flashback?), but I don't see how it makes sense if S01E04 takes place *before*. (In particular, I think the chronological sequence for the 100% UL parts should be 1st S01E07 and then S01E05 and then finally S01E04.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a later episode

> S03E03 Takagi: Because I know everything about you.

> [image]

> This is when Takagi reveals knowing about a TV programme that Nishikata looked forward to watching. Takagi just knows in general I guess. I guess it's not really to do with the 100% Unrequited Love.